Issues while setting up websocket for graphql subscription
I am trying to make a chat interface. I am using Nexjs in my frontend along with @tanstack-react-query. I have setup my graphql server with apollo server. I have setup the subscription in the server. But I am having issues while connecting it with my client. I am not using Apollo Client.
I am getting error: 'useMessage.tsx:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/subscription' failed'
This is my hook which wil run when the chat is mounted.
import { SUBSCRIBE_MESSAGE } from "@/lib/query";
import { useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const url = "ws://localhost:4000/subscription";

export const useMessage = (channelId:string|null) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [isSubscribing, setIsSubscribing] = useState(false);
  const [isSubscribingSuccess, setIsSubscribingSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [ws, setWs] = useState<WebSocket | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (channelId) {
      // Check if channelId is not null
      const newWs = new WebSocket(url, "graphql-ws");
      setWs(newWs); // Save WebSocket instance in state

      return () => {
        // Clean up WebSocket connection on component unmount
        if (newWs) {
          newWs.close();
        }
      };
    }
  }, [channelId]); // Trigger effect only when channelId changes

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ws && channelId) {
      // Check if ws and channelId are both truthy
      // WebSocket connection established
      ws.onopen = () => {
        setIsSubscribing(true);
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "connection_init", payload: {} }));
        ws.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            id: "1",
            type: "start",
            payload: {
              // Your subscription payload here
              query: SUBSCRIBE_MESSAGE,
              variables: { channelId }, // Pass channelId as a variable
            },
          })
        );
      };

      ws.onmessage = (event) => {
        const msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log("message", msg);
        if (msg.type === "data") {
          console.log("invalidate now");
        }
        // Add logic to handle other message types if needed
      };

      ws.onerror = (error) => {
        // Handle WebSocket errors
        console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
        setIsSubscribingSuccess(false);
      };

      ws.onclose = () => {
        // Handle WebSocket closing
        console.log("WebSocket connection closed");
        setIsSubscribingSuccess(false);
      };
    }
  }, [ws, channelId]); // Trigger effect only when ws or channelId changes

  return { isSubscribing, isSubscribingSuccess };
};


and this is how I've setup my server  websocket
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from "@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Prisma, PrismaClient, User } from "@prisma/client";
import { DefaultArgs } from "@prisma/client/runtime/library";
import schema from "./graphql/index";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "@graphql-tools/schema";
import { WebSocketServer } from "ws";
import { useServer } from "graphql-ws/lib/use/ws";
import { PubSub } from "graphql-subscriptions";

export interface MyContext {
  prisma: PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, never, DefaultArgs>;
  SECRET: string;
  SECRET2: string;
  user?: User;
  pubsub?: PubSub;
}

export async function createGraphqlServer(httpServer: any, pubsub: PubSub) {
  const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,

    path: "/subscription",
  });

  const serverCleanup = useServer(
    {
      schema,
      context: async (ctx, msg, args) => {
        return { pubsub };
      },
    },
    wsServer
  );
  const server = new ApolloServer<MyContext>({
    schema,
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      {
        async serverWillStart() {
          return {
            async drainServer() {
              await serverCleanup.dispose();
            },
          };
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  await server.start();
  return server;
}


and this is my resolver for my message:

import { Resolvers } from "../types";
import { PubSub, withFilter } from "graphql-subscriptions";

const NEW_CHANNEL_MESSAGE = "NEW_CHANNEL_MESSAGE";

const messageResolvers: Resolvers = {
  // createMessage:()
  Query: {
    getMessages: async (parent, { channelId }, { prisma, user }) => {
      try {
        // if (!user) throw new Error("Unauthenticatd");
        const messages = prisma.messages.findMany({
          where: { channelId },
          include: { user: { select: { userId: true, username: true } } },
          orderBy: { createdAt: "asc" },
        });
        return messages;
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    createMessage: async (
      parent,
      { text, channelId },
      { prisma, user, pubsub }
    ) => {
      try {
        if (!user) throw new Error("Unauthenticated");

        const message = await prisma.messages.create({
          data: {
            text,
            channelId,
            userId: user.userId,
          },
        });

        pubsub?.publish(NEW_CHANNEL_MESSAGE, {
          newChannelMessage: message,
          channelId: channelId,
        });

        return true;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("d", err);
        return false;
      }
    },
  },

  Subscription: {
    newChannelMessage: {
      subscribe: withFilter(
        (_, __, { pubsub }: { pubsub: PubSub }) =>
          pubsub.asyncIterator(NEW_CHANNEL_MESSAGE),
        (payload, args) => payload.channelId === args.channelId
      ),
    },
  },

I am connecting to the endpoint I've specified in the backend but it seems to be failing.
